# Directory Searcher Filter is returning no results

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap-query

Definitely not experienced enough to know why this is returning no results. I cannot use the PricipalContext library and must use the Directory Searcher option in place. Groups exist like this "MB-X-Approvers", "MB-Y-Approvers", "MB-Z-Approvers", etc.

```
        public IEnumerable<Mailbox> GetAprMailboxes()
        {
            IEnumerable<Mailbox> mailBoxes = new List<Mailbox>();
            try
            {
                DirectorySearcher directorySearch = GetDirectorySearcher();
                
                var who = @"CN=lastName\, Firstname,OU=USERS,OU=HOUSTON,DC=mydomain,DC=net"


                var strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(member=" + who + ")(cn=MB-*-Approvers))";

                directorySearch.Filter = strFilter;

                var searchResults = directorySearch.FindAll();

        //Do stuff with results and add to mailbox list

            return mailBoxes;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHelper.LogException(ex);
            }
        }
        
        public DirectorySearcher GetDirectorySearcher()
        {
            DirectorySearcher directorySearch = null;
            try
            {
                var baseEntry = new DirectoryEntry
                {
                    Path = "LDAP://ldapquery.mydomain.net/DC=mydomain,DC=net",
                    Username = "ADUserName",
                    Password = "ADPassword",
                    AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure
                };
                
                directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(baseEntry);
                directorySearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                directorySearch.SizeLimit = 5000;
                directorySearch.PageSize = 1000;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }

            return directorySearch;
        }
```

Comment: I tried a similar query in our environment and it worked, so I can't say why you don't get results. Just verify your data. Is the DN of your user correct? Is the `cn` of the group what you expect? There are various name-type attributes: `cn`, `sAMAccountName`, and (for distribution lists) `displayName`, all of which can be different.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Thank you for the pointer. See the comment I left below on jwilleke's answer. You were both correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, DNs like "cn=MB-*-Approvers" will not work for substring searches.

When using the DN syntax, therefore, the client must use the fully Qualified DN

Might want to try something like:

```
(&
    (member=*)
    (|(MB-X-Approvers,cn=groups,DC=mydomain,DC=net, ,cn=groups,DC=mydomain,DC=net, ,cn=groups,DC=mydomain,DC=net))
)
```

-jim

Comment: The `cn` attribute is not a DN, so wildcards, even in the middle, are ok. Also, the query you show isn't a valid LDAP query.

Comment: I found this to work. I ended up going another way as the DNs exact values were not known and could change at any time. A dynamic solution was "(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=MB-*-Approvers))" and then a linq query on "member" property returned based on the value of the "who" variable listed above. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @GabrielLuci While you are correct about the wildcards, the issue was that the user was in the "managedby" property and not in the "member" property. Also, the query shown by jwlleke is a search filter string for the DirectorySearcher.Filter property.

Comment: The `managedBy` attribute is what you want? That's the user who manages the DL (and can usually modify the membership), but is not necessarily a member.

Comment: Again, you are correct and again, this is a special case. I won't explain further for the purpose of protecting my position.